# For given list of Domain, I need to return the list of their labels in Python

Tags: python, list

I have a types of labels as 'Commercial', 'Organization', 'network', 'Information' which corresponds to domains .com, .org, .net, .info respectively.
Here, for the given list of domains I am trying to return the list of labels.

Eg: If input is `["en.wiki.org", "codesignal.com", "happy.net", "code.info"]`

then output should be as `["organization", "commercial", "network", "information"]`

I have written the code as below in Python:

```
def retrieveDomain(domains):
  domain_name= [elem.split('.')[-1] for elem in domains]

  for domain in domain_name:
    if domain=='com':
      return 'commercial'
    elif domain=='org':
      return 'organization'
    elif domain=='net':
      return 'network'
    elif domain=='info':
      return 'information'
    else:
      return 'Sorry! Domain not recognized...'
```

But I am getting the output for only the first element in the list as `'organization'` whereas I am supposed to get the output for all the elements in the list as 
`["organization", "commercial", "network", "information"]`

Request you to help me with where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`return` immediately stops the function and returns whatever you tell it to. You need to gather a list of results instead. E.g.:

```
def tld_to_tag(tld):
    if tld == 'com':
        return 'commercial'
    elif tld == 'org':
        return 'organization'
    elif tld == 'net':
        return 'network'
    elif tld == 'info':
        return 'information'
    else:
        return 'unknown'

def domains_to_tags(domains):
    tlds = [elem.split('.')[-1] for elem in domains]
    return [tld_to_tag(tld) for tld in tlds]
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you exit your `for` loop after the first iteration because you have a `return` for all the conditions you defined.

As a side note, instead of writing several if conditions, you can create a mapping which will convert the domain to it's corresponding label:

```
# mapping for domain-label conversion
domains_mapping = {"com": "Commercial", 
                   "org": "Organization", 
                   "net": "network", 
                   "info": "Information"}

urls = ["en.wiki.org", "codesignal.com", "happy.net", "code.info"]

# using list comprehension, we extract the domain for each url and get the corresponding label using our mapping
output = [domains_mapping.get(u.split(".")[-1]) for u in urls]

print(output)  # ['Organization', 'Commercial', 'network', 'Information']
```

Comment: Why not just define the dict? Zipping two lists is error prone in the long run

Comment: Just because the OP has already 2 lists. I am not sure how are they generated. If they are defined manually, I agree it would be better to create a dictionary without zip.

Comment: OP does not have two lists. They have a nested if-statement.

Comment: @MadPhysicist you are right! Thanks for your comment.